# Episerver reCAPTCHA Element - Server-Side Validation Query

Tags: recaptcha, episerver, episerver-forms

I have an Episerver form with a **reCAPTCHA** element, and the keys are configured on the Google Console, working seamlessly. However, over the past few days, the site has been experiencing numerous form submissions, seemingly from bot accounts. These submissions appear suspicious as they don't seem to be the work of genuine users.

My question is:

Is a custom implementation required for server-side validation when using the reCAPTCHA element, or is adding the reCAPTCHA element with a higher score as part of the form setup sufficient?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Yes, you should implement server-side validation of the token as well.

Comment: Thanks Ted for the response. So if a server side implementation is required for token validation why will some one need episerver recaptcha element?  Why not go for a custom recaptcha element from scratch that will have more control rather than using episerver's element & overwriting it. I couldn't find any article related to episerver recaptcha element to have a custom implementation. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Server-side validation *is* part of the Forms CAPTCHA element.